# How To give title according to condition while Exporting to Excel?

Tags: .net, excel, export-to-excel

While Exporting the grid into excel. I have a condition according to which i have to give the title(not column heading) of the excel sheet.

ViewType = 'All'
Title = 'All Vendor Contract'

ViewType = 'Uploaded'
Title = 'All Signed Vendor Contract'

ViewType = 'Not Uploaded'
Title = 'All UnSigend Vendor Contract'

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDirectory);
        }

        var filename = "VendorContract" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".xlsx";
        var savePath = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, filename);
        var loadURL = _configuration["BManageUrl"] + uploadPath + filename;
        ViewType = (ViewType == null) ? "All" : ViewType;
        var VendorDocumentList = _bsDocumentService.GetDocumentVendorContractList(ContractNumber, CurrentUserDetails.SellerID, ViewType);
        ExcelHelper.ListToExcel<DocVendorContractViewModel>(VendorDocumentList, savePath);

        return Ok(loadURL);
    }
```

The expected output in excel (IF View Type is All)

All Vendor Contract // this is title

Number   ID  Name //this 3 are heading of the column

(1)        (22)   (acb)  //this 3 are the data

(2)        (23)   (asdasd)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me, but are you looking for a `switch`?

```
        switch (ViewType)
        {
            case "All":
                Title = "All Vendor Contract";
                break;
            case "Uploaded":
                Title = "All Signed Vendor Contract";
                break;
            case "Not Uploaded":
                Title = "All UnSigned Vendor Contract";
                break;
            default:
                Title = "Wrong ViewType";
                break;
        }
```

Or you could do the same with

```
        if (ViewType == "All")
        {
            Title = "All Vendor Contract";
        }
        else if (ViewType == "Uploaded")
        {
            Title = "All Signed Vendor Contract";
        }
        else if (ViewType == "Not Uploaded")
        {
            Title = "All UnSigned Vendor Contract";
        }
        else
        {
            Title = "Wrong ViewType";
        }
```

It is a matter of taste.

I cannot help you with the creation of your excel sheet, coz I don't know the

```
    var VendorDocumentList = _bsDocumentService.GetDocumentVendorContractList(ContractNumber, CurrentUserDetails.SellerID, ViewType);
    ExcelHelper.ListToExcel<DocVendorContractViewModel>(VendorDocumentList, savePath);
```

This is non-public code, so unless you publish this code you have to find it out yourself.

Comment: I confused you. It's not about the case. I just want to add title while exporting to excel. Like shown here https://www.screencast.com/t/tFfU98Th

Comment: OK. As I stated before, your code is not public, so I cannot help you with that. I can only see, that it isn't a title (as in filename or sheetname). It's just data on the first row. Just add a row to your `VendorDocumentList` before your data and fill it with your 'Title'.